# Change cloned element on draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using draggable function with JQuery UI. And i want to change my cloned element with this code for to change my cloned element :

This is my script code :

```
$("li").draggable({
    helper:'clone',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("li-drag");
        $(this).addClass("ui-widget-content");
    }               
});
```

But my $(this) element change the original element...

How can i change my cloned element into start function?

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/TMkG8/)

```
$("li").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).closest('ul').find('li:last').addClass("color_").addClass('li-drag').addClass("ui-widget-content");;
    }
});
```

when `clone` is created it is the last object in the parent so to `addClass` to the clone we can do

`$(this).closest('ul').find('li:last')`

or

`$(this).parents('ul').find('li:last')`

or

`$(this).parent().find('li:last')`